# Realise accumulated DataFrame from a column of Boolean values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Be the following python pandas DataFrame:

| ID | Holidays | visit_1 | visit_2 | visit_3 | other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | True | 1 | 2 | 0 | red |
| 0 | False | 3 | 2 | 0 | red |
| 0 | True | 4 | 4 | 1 | blue |
| 1 | False | 2 | 0 | 0 | red |
| 1 | True | 1 | 2 | 1 | green |
| 2 | False | 1 | 0 | 0 | red |

Currently I calculate a new DataFrame with the accumulated visit values as follows.

```
# Calculate the columns of the total visit count
visit_df = df.groupby('ID')[['visit_1', 'visit_2', 'visit_3']].sum()
```

I would like to create a new one taking into account only the rows whose Holiday value is True. How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple subset the rows first:

```
df[df['Holidays']].groupby('ID')[['visit_1', 'visit_2', 'visit_3']].sum()
```

output:

```
    visit_1  visit_2  visit_3
ID                           
0         5        6        1
1         1        2        1
```

Alternative if you want to also get the groups without any match:

```
df2 = df.set_index('ID')

(df2.where(df2['Holidays'])
   .groupby('ID')[['visit_1', 'visit_2', 'visit_3']].sum()
)
```

output:

```
    visit_1  visit_2  visit_3
ID                           
0       5.0      6.0      1.0
1       1.0      2.0      1.0
2       0.0      0.0      0.0
```

###### variant

```
df2 = df.set_index('ID')

(df2.where(df2['Holidays'])
   .groupby('ID')[['visit_1', 'visit_2', 'visit_3']].sum()
   .convert_dtypes()
   .add_suffix('_Holidays')
)
```

output:

```
    visit_1_Holidays  visit_2_Holidays  visit_3_Holidays
ID                                                      
0                  5                 6                 1
1                  1                 2                 1
2                  0                 0                 0
```

Comment: The second option suits me better, thank you. How could I add a suffix to the new columns? Something like visit_1_Holidays, visit_2_Holidays, visit_3_Holidays. And I prefer values in integer form.

Comment: simply `.add_suffix('_Holidays')` and `.convert_dtypes()` to have integers ;)

Comment: Any way to make the suffix the same name as the column used? In this case Holidays. In case I apply another column with similar characteristics.